# South ignores change in field default value in Python / Django

Tags: python, django, django-south

Why does South not recognize changes in default field values in Python models?  For example, take this existing model that is migrated with south:

```
class MyFamily(models.Model):
    family_size = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="What is your family size?", default=2)
```

Now, I'd like to change the default value from two to four.  However, when schemamigrating the module, South reports:

```
python manage.py schemamigration family --auto change_default_from_two_to_four_for_size

Running migrations for family:
- Nothing to migrate.
    - Loading initial data for family.
```

I could manually update the initial migration, and use the SQL to directly update the field, but that's a pain.  Is there a South command I haven't found that recognizes the change in the default?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

South won't update the default value for existing columns, because it matters for him only when adding a new column to a non empty table. The `django orm` will handle writing the new default value to new rows before hitting the database.

If you will work on the database from outside `django orm`, you have to update it manually.

More explanations [*south/db.add_column*](http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/db.add_column)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately we hit the DB from PHP as well, so I will probably have to change it manually.  It's just strange that South can't change the default.  ;-)

Comment: What I did is basically comment the field, schemamigration / migrate and uncomment again. My database was empty anyway